# Trying to create a table with multiple select statements

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Here is a sample of the two select statements that pull up the information that I need but need to be merged essentially so it can be read as one table.

```sql
SELECT  
    DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time),  
    sum(tran_qty) as 'Units Sorted'  
    FROM t_tran_log with(nolock)  
    WHERE tran_type = '311'  
    and cast(start_tran_date as date)='2021-07-03'  
    group by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)  
    order by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)

SELECT  
    DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time),  
    sum(tran_qty) as 'Total Picked'  
    FROM t_tran_log with(nolock)  
    WHERE tran_type = '301'  
    and cast(start_tran_date as date)='2021-07-03'  
    group by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)  
    order by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: TSQL Jeopardy: What is [`union all`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert result from both the queries sequentially

```
SELECT
DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time),
sum(tran_qty) as 'Units Sorted'
FROM t_tran_log with(nolock)
WHERE tran_type = '311'
and cast(start_tran_date as date)='2021-07-03'
group by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)

union all
SELECT
DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time),
sum(tran_qty) as 'Total Picked'
FROM t_tran_log with(nolock)
WHERE tran_type = '301'
and cast(start_tran_date as date)='2021-07-03'
group by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)
```

If order by is necessary then:

```
select * from 
   (
        SELECT
        DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)start_tran_hour,
        sum(tran_qty) as 'Units Sorted'
        FROM t_tran_log with(nolock)
        WHERE tran_type = '311'
        and cast(start_tran_date as date)='2021-07-03'
        group by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)
    
        union all
        SELECT
        DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)start_tran_hour,
        sum(tran_qty) as 'Total Picked'
        FROM t_tran_log with(nolock)
        WHERE tran_type = '301'
        and cast(start_tran_date as date)='2021-07-03'
        group by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)
    )t order by start_tran_hour
```

If you want to place results from both query side by side then you can join results from both queries:

```
    select A.start_tran_hour,[Units Sorted],[Total Picked]
    from
    (
        SELECT
        DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)start_tran_hour,
        sum(tran_qty) as [Units Sorted]
        FROM t_tran_log with(nolock)
        WHERE tran_type = '311'
        and cast(start_tran_date as date)='2021-07-03'
        group by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)
    )A
    inner join        
    (
        SELECT
        DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)start_tran_hour,
        sum(tran_qty) as [Total Picked]
        FROM t_tran_log with(nolock)
        WHERE tran_type = '301'
        and cast(start_tran_date as date)='2021-07-03'
        group by DATEPART(hour,start_tran_time)
    )B
    on A.start_tran_hour=B.start_tran_hour
    order by A.start_tran_hour
```

Comment: I did try union and just now union all but it gives this when running Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.

Comment: Just remove order by clause.

Comment: That did the trick in terms of combining the data the only problem is that it put both data sets into one column Units Sorted instead of Units Sorted and Total Picked.

Comment: For some reason this is the result from one of the column 0  Units Sorted Total Picked. Its putting Units Sorted Total Picked in the data portion instead of the column name.

Comment: Would you please share some sample data!

Comment: select A.start_tran_hour, [Units Sorted], [Total Picked]

Comment: That did it just have [] instead of ''

Comment: Thank you Kazi for all of your help!

Comment: Sorry @cstoli. I didn't notice your dbms. Best wishes.

Comment: Hi Kazi I had one more question if I want to add more statements how do I modify the on statement (on A.start_tran_hour=B.start_tran_hour) to add more?